# Using a font that came with a Mac App Store app in other apps

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, font

I'm sort of generally curious about this, since pre-Mac App Store apps one could simply open the font file from within the app's package contents and install it through Font Book to allow use outside that particular app.

When I use Add Fonts from within Font Book to add the fonts, I get the following 2 "serious errors":

> Corrupt font name
>   - Font basic parsability
>   - System Validation

Now, is this something I'm just not supposed to be doing? As in, am I breaking a rule here? I'm not using these fonts for publication or commercial use - I just want them available throughout the system.

Comment: What app is this? It could be they did some custom/proprietary fussing with the font file to make it invalid in general, but still readable to the app. (This fussing could be anything from simply reordering the file's header data to encrypting the file with a key the app has stored internally.)

Comment: Could be. The app in question is iA Writer.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of iA Writer, they licensed a commercial font called Nitti Light for use in their application and their application only. That's why you cannot copy it into FontBook and use it elsewhere. Try Cousine from Google Fonts for a free font that is quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

It may be they did some custom/proprietary fussing with the font file to make it invalid in general, but still readable to the app. (This fussing could be anything from simply reordering the file's header data to encrypting the file with a key the app has stored internally.)

If so, it's probably that the app's makers licensed the font for use in their app and not for general distribution.

Comment: I wondered if it wasn't something related to licensing. Is there any way to tell (other than implicitly through Font Book's validation failure, I mean)?

Comment: No idea. Maybe email the app's creators to ask? Maybe they'll tell you who they licensed the font from and you can buy it from them.